# Boost_LIBRARIES doesn't contain program_options

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

When building my project, Boost_LIBRARIES doesn't contain program_options even though it is required and found. If I add it manually, it works fine. My CMake contains the following:

```
find_package(Boost 1.60.0 REQUIRED COMPONENTS program_options thread system regex)
message("${Boost_LIBRARIES}")
include_directories(include ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS})
target_link_libraries (proj ${Boost_LIBRARIES} boost_program_options)
```

CMake claims that the library was found, but it is not listed in the call to `message("${Boost_LIBRARIES}")`

Comment: What CMake version do you use?

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite your code for modern CMake:

```
find_package(Boost 1.60.0 REQUIRED COMPONENTS program_options thread system regex)

add_executable(proj ...)
target_link_libraries(proj Boost::program_options ...)
```

And forget about resulting `Boost_BLAH_LBAH` variables and `include_directories` + `link_directories`.

If smth goes wrong w/ Boost finder, add `-DBoost_DEBUG=ON` to `cmake` command line. 
If smth goes wrong w/ (any/generic) `find_package` add `-DCMAKE_FIND_DEBUG_MODE=ON`.

See also for inspiration: https://steveire.wordpress.com/2017/11/05/embracing-modern-cmake/

Comment: I'm using Cmake v. 2.8. I do have the `add_executable` line, but I decided to only show the Boost-related items. While I did not know you could use the `Boost::` syntax in the linkage, my main concern was why I couldn't do the job with just `${Boost_LIBRARIES}`. I think it's far more elegant to be able to place one Boost-related link rather than declaring each component. Essentially, what do I need to do to get rid of `boost_program_options`?

Comment: Take a look to `FindBoost.cmake` shipped w/ your version (2.8.what? .12?) if it contains `add_library(... IMPORTED ...)`. If so, you can use _imported targets_ instead of variables.

Comment: If you have the only target in a project linked to Boost, then `${Boost_LIBRARIES}` is "fine" (for old CMake w/o imported targets). Otherwise, and my IMHO always, better to use `${Boost_<INDIVIDUAL>_LIBRARY}` to explicit control what libraries particular target is linked to.

Comment: and BTW, why do you have relatively fresh Boost version, but so old CMake?? Modern CMake and 2.8.smth is a big difference!

Comment: We've been basing our CMake files off of old templates for so long, we haven't changed. We most likely have the latest installed but are only requiring 2.8. Probably a good thing to update.

Comment: Add your relevant comments to the post, and I'll give you the answer.